# SSH with passphrase on three servers

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I have three servers A,B, and C. I need to do is to run something like:

```
my_self@A:~$ ssh B "ssh C run_a_script_here"
```

This works if I have my ssh keys setup correctly on A,B,C, and I do not use SSH passphrase. But if I run this as a different user who has a SSH passphrase, I got an error:

```
user_has_passphrase@A:~$ ssh B "ssh C run_a_script_here"
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
user_has_passphrase@A: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I set the keychain for user_has_passphrase on A and B, and I can do a ssh B from A, then do a ssh C on B without any issues.

I am not sure if I use passphrase, I can even do the chain ssh or not.

Any idea?

Thanks, Philip

Comment: (1) Just to avoid misunderstandings, please confirm you mean a passphrase, not a password (they are different concepts, compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1576115/432690)). (2) There is `ssh -J B C` which is *not* equivalent to `ssh B 'ssh C'` (see the beginning of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1565588/432690)), but maybe you can use it.

Comment: Right, passphrase, the one that used to encrypt the key file, not the password.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use interactions which check for (pseudo-) terminals, such as `sudo` authentication or, in this case, key authentication with a passphrase, you can use the `-t` switch for `ssh` to, according to the manual, will:

> Force pseudoterminal allocation.

This can be chained, if needed, e. g.

```
$ ssh -t B "ssh -t C run_a_script_here"
```